# How to create a list of word pairs

Tags: python, list, cpu-word

I want to create a list of word pairs, separated by tabs, from a word list. I think one option could be to create a matrix with "range" because i want to have all words combined with each other. I need the list of word pairs to make further analyses.

From a word list:

```
mama
papa
sister
brother
```

should be the output

```
mama papa
sister brother
mama sister
papa sister
brother mama
```

and so on....

Someone who knows what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I have tried different scripts that I have collected through other projekts, unfortunately without success! thats why I am asking here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
words = ["mama", "papa", "sister", "brother"]
pairs = list(itertools.permutations(words, 2))
print pairs
```

Note the use of permutations which I think is what you may be asking for.

Comment: Maybe `itertools.permutations(words, 2)` ? 'repeat' is an invalid keyword for this function.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, but i have some problems with unicodes, although  "# -*- coding: utf8 -*-" they are still being corrupted. How can I make the output utf8 readable?

Answer (score 7):

```
words = ["mama", "papa", "sister", "brother"]
pairs = list(itertools.product(words, repeat=2))
print pairs
```

prints

```
[('mama', 'mama'),
 ('mama', 'papa'),
 ('mama', 'sister'),
 ('mama', 'brother'),
 ('papa', 'mama'),
 ('papa', 'papa'),
 ('papa', 'sister'),
 ('papa', 'brother'),
 ('sister', 'mama'),
 ('sister', 'papa'),
 ('sister', 'sister'),
 ('sister', 'brother'),
 ('brother', 'mama'),
 ('brother', 'papa'),
 ('brother', 'sister'),
 ('brother', 'brother')]
```